# Why Feedly API did not return ALL ids entries in stream of category?

Tags: java, scala, api, rss, feedly

I trying to use API for little category, contains just one "Bloomberg Businessweek".
My app is using java and scala, but i proving problem in curl:

> curl -H 'Authorization: OAuth ...'
>   'https://cloud.feedly.com/v3/streams/ids?streamId=user/.../category/...&unreadOnly=false&count=2000000&ranked=oldest' > ec1.txt

Result

> cat ec1.txt

```
{"ids":["ElprbHlVAORBPyAjLJJOZoHng3kkYQhPEDVNiGmVpWE=_1700d3ebe9b:7639f2f:fd9c96c2","ElprbHlVAORBPyAjLJJOZoHng3kkYQhPEDVNiGmVpWE=_170108a3578:7d57149:31d4c877",..."ElprbHlVAORBPyAjLJJOZoHng3kkYQhPEDVNiGmVpWE=_170a63c7c10:3aa2f8:c087a336"]}
```

The size of list is only 49, it did not contains many entries, for example:

https://feedly.com/i/entry/ElprbHlVAORBPyAjLJJOZoHng3kkYQhPEDVNiGmVpWE=_13e8e581f60:21786c8:70d63bab

> cat ec1.txt | grep 13e8e581f60:21786c8:70d63bab

gives nothing.

What did i do wrong? Thanks for any help. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This endpoint has a limit of 5,000 entries (2,500 for tags), so requesting 2,000,000 entries won't do much good...

The `ranked=oldest` option only works if the streamId is a single feed. If you pass a category, the API only returns the past 31 days. So if you pass `streamId=feed%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.bloomberg.com%2Ffeed%2Fpodcast%2Fhays-advantage.xml` you should see entries all the way back to 2013 for this feed.

I hope this helps.

Comment: No, i am afraid 'https://cloud.feedly.com/v3/streams/ids?streamId=feed%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.bloomberg.com%2Ffeed%2Fpodcast%2Fhays-advantage.xml&unreadOnly=false&count=5000&ranked=oldest' >ec1.txt
gives 51 enties, i think it really in 31 days, and there is no option fot change it. (

Comment: We deployed a patch yesterday: there was indeed a 31 day limit for developer tokens, but I removed it. If you try again it should work now.